# yum in dockerfile - There are no enabled repos

Tags: linux, maven, docker, yum

I am having issues with installing python3 with yum in dockerfile. I did look on internet, I did try few things, not working. Its just small thing but not able to figure it out. When I try to build below docker file I do get error . I get error at line -

RUN yum install -y oracle-epel-release-el7

```
There are no enabled repos.
 Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
 You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
```

The docker file is below.

```
FROM openjdk:13-jdk-slim
ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.6.3
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"
ARG SHA=c35a1803a6e70a126e80b2b3ae33eed961f83ed74d18fcd16909b2d44d7dada3203f1ffe726c17ef8dcca2dcaa9fca676987befeadc9b9f759967a8cb77181c0
ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries

# Install prerequisites
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y yum


RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
  && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
  && echo "${SHA}  /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
  && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  && rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"



# Install Python 3.6
RUN yum install -y oracle-epel-release-el7
RUN yum install -y python36

# Install AWS CLI
RUN pip3 install awscli


CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: The error message is quite informative. You need to add or enable the repo in which the desired package resides...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why mix `apt` and `yum`? You're already using `apt-get`, just use it to install your python too:

```
apt-get install python3.6
```